# nodejs ftp-srv: "SocketError: The given address is not yours

Tags: node.js, ftp, command-line-interface

I'm creating a cli script to share files between users using a local [ftp server](https://github.com/autovance/ftp-srv) and ngrok tunneling.

I have this code that will start the server but from filezilla I'm unable to connect correctly.

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

/**
 * Simple cli FTP files sharing script
 */
const path = require('path');
const ngrok = require('ngrok');
const FtpServer = require('ftp-srv');

const sharedFolder = path.format({dir: __dirname, base: '/shared'})
const ftpAddress = 'ftp://127.0.0.1:21021';


const ftpServer = new FtpServer({
    url: ftpAddress,
    anonymous: true,
    greeting: 'Hello user!'
});

ftpServer.on('login', (data, resolve, reject) => {
    console.log(data);
    resolve({root: sharedFolder});
});

ftpServer.listen().then( async () => {
    const tunnel = await ngrok.connect({proto: 'tcp', addr: 21021});
    console.log(`FTP Server is running on ${ftpAddress}, pubilc tunnel link is: ${tunnel}`);
});
```

In VS console while the script is running I get this error after filezilla connect to the server using the tunnel link generated from ngrok. Also I'm not able to see the welcome message.

```
":"127.0.0.1","directive":"PORT","level":50,"err":{"message":"The given address is not yours","name":"SocketError","stack":"SocketError: The given address is not yours
```

**UPDATE**

In filezilla I get this error after the connection is created

```
Stato:          Risoluzione dell'indirizzo IP 4.tcp.ngrok.io in corso
Stato:          Connessione a 3.138.180.119:15947...
Stato:          Connessione stabilita, in attesa del messaggio di benvenuto...
Risposta:   220-Hello user!
Risposta:   220 Features: a .
Comando:    AUTH TLS
Risposta:   502 Command not supported
Comando:    AUTH SSL
Risposta:   504 Command parameter not supported
Stato:          Server non sicuro. Non supporta FTP su TLS.
Comando:    USER anonymous
Risposta:   530 log is not defined
Errore:         Impossibile collegarsi al server
```

Is there any solution?

Comment: FileZilla is using TLS and the server doesn't support it. Use unsecured FTP. Not FTPS (FTP over ssl)

Comment: I'm not using FTPS

Comment: Is this error when connecting through ngrok, or direct to local host?

Comment: It's related to filezilla when tries to connect to the link provided from ngrok

Comment: Are you able to connect directly from FileZilla to the the ftp server NOT using ngrok?

Comment: yes, if I enter the local address `127.0.0.1:21021` in filezilla I'm able to connect and I see the folder I've set as server root